# How do I use HTML.fromhtml in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a NSString notification like this: "You must pay 4.00 dollar.".The money has a red color.In Android ,I can use HTML.formhtml do it.But I don't know how to do it in IOS.Who can help me?

Comment: try CATextLayer to change Font color(using multi color) else using uiwebview to display html string

Comment: I don't want to ues uiwebview.

Comment: what do you mean by `NSString notification`? Where do you want to present such string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
CATextLayer *aTextLayer_= [[[CATextLayer alloc]init] autorelease];
    aTextLayer_.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 50);
    aTextLayer_.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    aTextLayer_.foregroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    aTextLayer_.alignmentMode=kCAAlignmentCenter;
    aTextLayer_.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    aTextLayer_ .wrapped=YES;
    [aTextLayer_ setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentLeft];

    UIFont *smallFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
    CTFontRef ctSmallFont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)smallFont.fontName, smallFont.pointSize, NULL);

    UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:25];
    CTFontRef ctBoldFont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)boldFont.fontName, boldFont.pointSize, NULL);

    CGColorRef cgColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    CGColorRef cgColor1 = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                (id)ctSmallFont, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                cgColor, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

    NSDictionary *subattributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   (id)ctBoldFont, (id)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                   cgColor1, (id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    CFRelease(ctBoldFont);
    NSString *subString=@"You must pay 4.00 dollar.";
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:subString attributes:attributes];

    [attrStr addAttributes:subattributes range:NSMakeRange(13,4)];
    aTextLayer_.string=attrStr;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:aTextLayer_];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a `UIWebView` your best options is to use a `NSAttributedString`.

A naive implementation without caring too much about corner cases and error checking would be something like

```
NSString * string = @"You must pay 4.00 dollar";
NSString * pattern = @"You must pay (.+) dollar";
NSRegularExpression * regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:NULL];
NSArray * matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
NSRange priceRange = [matches[0] rangeAtIndex:1];
NSMutableAttributedString * attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
[attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:priceRange];
```

Note that I assumed that your patter will always be `You must pay (.+) dollar`. In case it's different simply adjust the regex in order to retrieve the `NSRange` of the substring that needs to be stylized.

Then you can use the attributed string as a content of anything accepting a `NSAttributedString`, for instance `UILabel` has an `attributedText` property since iOS 6, therefore you could do something like

```
yourLabel.attributedText = attrString;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add html code to UIWebView

```
  [_webView loadHTMLString:@"<p>You must pay <font color=\"red\">4.00</font> dollar. </p> " baseURL:nil];
```

try this code

-----------------Alternate Option----------------------------

If this text format is going to be fixed (You must pay XXXX.XXX dollar.) better Create custom component

1. Create class extend UIView
2. Add UILable with different font color